# Loading XLL in Excel: any difference between Tools->AddIn and File->Open?

Tags: excel, load, add-in, xll

I have got an XLL, and want to load it in Excel.

Is there any difference between loading using Tools->AddIn or File->Open other than

- it is impossible to unload it if I use File->Open;
- it won't be loaded automatically if I restart Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are writing an xll and not a VBA add-in, see the full story at http://xllblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/add-in-manager/.

Long story short, `File>Open...` only calls `xlAutoOpen`. The Add-in Manager calls `xlAutoAdd` then `xlAutoOpen` when you add the file, and `xlAutoRemove` then `xlAutoClose` when you remove the file.

Answer (score 3):

Tools->Addin fires an additional event AddinInstall the first time the addin is installed. Personally I never use this event.
If you want to load an XLL using VBA then you have to use RegisterXLL

Comment: I think from VBA you can also load the .xll with Application.Addins.Add("...path..").Installed = true. Not sure what the difference is between that and RegisterXLL.